# Re-Spin Wheel after Complete Stop

Tags: javascript, html, animation

How can I re-spin the wheel below, after it comes to a stop. Having one of those days where I just can't figure it out.

I created a resetWheel function that resets the wheel once it comes to a complete stop. I tried inserting it once the wheel is locked and stopped, but it refuses to work with me. Thank you in advance for the feedback and help. Feel free to add to my existing code, since I'm still fairly new, any advice is good !

```js
function rand(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

var color = ['#6897bb', '#6dc066', '#f67f5c', '#cc5466', '#e6e6fa', '#fbc', '#f88', "#fbc", "#f67"];
var label = ['5', '3', '2', '1', '15', '6', '10', '0', "20", '0'];
var slices = color.length;
var sliceDeg = 360 / slices;
var deg = rand(0, 360);
var speed = 0;
var slowDownRand = 0;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var width = canvas.width; // size
var center = width / 2; // center
var isStopped = false;
var lock = false;
var logged = false;
let totalScore = 0;

function deg2rad(deg) {
    return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}

function drawSlice(deg, color) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.moveTo(center, center);
    ctx.arc(center, center, width / 2, deg2rad(deg), deg2rad(deg + sliceDeg));
    ctx.lineTo(center, center);
    ctx.fill();
}

function drawText(deg, text) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(center, center);
    ctx.rotate(deg2rad(deg));
    ctx.textAlign = "right";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.font = 'bold 30px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillText(text, 130, 10);
    ctx.restore();
}

function drawImg() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, width);
    for (var i = 0; i < slices; i++) {
        drawSlice(deg, color[i]);
        drawText(deg + sliceDeg / 2, label[i]);
        deg += sliceDeg;
    }
}

drawImg();
function resetWheel() {
    (anim());
}

startSpin.addEventListener("click", function anim() {
    deg += speed;
    deg %= 360;

    // Increment speed
    if (!isStopped && speed < 3) {
        speed = speed + 1 * 0.1;
    }
    // Decrement Speed
    if (isStopped) {
        if (!lock) {
            lock = true;
            slowDownRand = rand(0.959, 0.998);
        }
        speed = speed > 0.2 ? speed *= slowDownRand : 0;
    }

    if (lock && !speed) {
        var ai = Math.floor(((360 - deg - 90) % 360) / sliceDeg); // deg 2 Array Index
        ai = (slices + ai) % slices; // Fix negative index
        let score = label[ai];
        if (!logged) {
            console.log(score);

            totalScore = totalScore + score;
            console.log(totalScore)
            logged = true;


        }

    }

    drawImg();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(anim);
});
document.getElementById("stopSpin").addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    isStopped = true;
    //setTimeout(loadPhrase, 2000); //waits for wheel to stop, then starts function
}, false);
```

```css
#wheel {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#wheel:after {
    content: "";
    background: red;
    border: 2px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-left: -7px;
    transform: rotate(45deg)
}
```

```html
    <div id="gameScreen">
        <div id="wheel">
            <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

        </div>

        <br>
        <button id="startSpin">Spin!</button>
        <button id="stopSpin">Stop!</button>
        <div id="gameWrapper">
            <h1 id="game_header">Guess The Correct Letters</h1>
            <div id="display">



            </div>
          
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is it because you never set isStopped to false again?

Comment: Looks great! To fix, remove your `click` handler and declare it as a normal function. in your click hander just use the handler name rather then declaring it there. The problem is that the variable `anim` is not available outside the handler.

Comment: Thank you ! You were right, declaring it as a normal function was the route to go. Should have noticed it earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Having one of those days where I just can't figure it out.

Oof that hit me on a personal level

Anyway, you're not setting `isStopped` back to false so your wheel won't spin also your `anim()` function isn't accessible anywhere else in your code so your reset function can't see it.

JS

```
function rand(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

var color = ['#6897bb', '#6dc066', '#f67f5c', '#cc5466', '#e6e6fa', '#fbc', '#f88', "#fbc", "#f67"];
var label = ['5', '3', '2', '1', '15', '6', '10', '0', "20", '0'];
var slices = color.length;
var sliceDeg = 360 / slices;
var deg = rand(0, 360);
var speed = 0;
var slowDownRand = 0;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var width = canvas.width; // size
var center = width / 2; // center
var isStopped = false;
var lock = false;
var logged = false;
let totalScore = 0;

function deg2rad(deg) {
    return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}

function drawSlice(deg, color) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.moveTo(center, center);
    ctx.arc(center, center, width / 2, deg2rad(deg), deg2rad(deg + sliceDeg));
    ctx.lineTo(center, center);
    ctx.fill();
}

function drawText(deg, text) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(center, center);
    ctx.rotate(deg2rad(deg));
    ctx.textAlign = "right";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
    ctx.font = 'bold 30px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillText(text, 130, 10);
    ctx.restore();
}

function drawImg() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, width);
    for (var i = 0; i < slices; i++) {
        drawSlice(deg, color[i]);
        drawText(deg + sliceDeg / 2, label[i]);
        deg += sliceDeg;
    }
}

function anim() {
    deg += speed;
    deg %= 360;

    // Increment speed
    if (!isStopped && speed < 3) {
        speed = speed + 1 * 0.1;
    }
    // Decrement Speed
    if (isStopped) {
        if (!lock) {
            lock = true;
            slowDownRand = rand(0.959, 0.998);
        }
        speed = speed > 0.2 ? speed *= slowDownRand : 0;
    }

    if (lock && !speed) {
        var ai = Math.floor(((360 - deg - 90) % 360) / sliceDeg); // deg 2 Array Index
        ai = (slices + ai) % slices; // Fix negative index
        let score = label[ai];
        if (!logged) {
            console.log(score);

            totalScore = totalScore + score;
            console.log(totalScore)
            logged = true;


        }

    }

    drawImg();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}

drawImg();

function resetWheel() {
  if(isStopped){
    isStopped = false;
    anim();
  }
}

startSpin.addEventListener("click", anim);
document.getElementById("stopSpin").addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    isStopped = true;
    //setTimeout(loadPhrase, 2000); //waits for wheel to stop, then starts function
}, false)

document.getElementById("restartSpin").addEventListener("click",resetWheel);
```

HTML (I've added a restart button)

```
 <div id="gameScreen">
        <div id="wheel">
            <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

        </div>

        <br>
        <button id="startSpin">Spin!</button>
        <button id="stopSpin">Stop!</button>
   <button id="restartSpin">Restart</button>
        <div id="gameWrapper">
            <h1 id="game_header">Guess The Correct Letters</h1>
            <div id="display">



            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Didn't even think about adding a restartSpin button.